# JavaScript Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm a novice backend developer and I've been tasked with adding some react features and I'm totally out of my depth.  The following code generates the exception "Cannot set property '1' of undefined".  The first element is id:1 and name:"".  I don't think the empty string has anything to do with my problem though since I've tried hardcoding a string and I get the same exception.

```
payment_code: {
    label: 'Payment Code',
    value: 'payment_code',
    choices: adminSalesStore.paymentCodes.map((payment_code) => {
        console.log(payment_code);
        console.log(payment_code['id']);
        console.log(payment_code['name']);
        displayChoices.payment_code[payment_code['id']] = payment_code['name'];
        return {
            label: payment_code['id'],
            value: payment_code['name']
        }
    }),
    type: 'choice'
},
```

I really don't understand the error because payment_code['id'] and payment_code['name'] are not null or undefined.  The log statements confirm this.  Sorry about the super basic question but I've googled the issue pretty extensively and this error still makes absolutely no sense.  There's similar functions in the same class and they all work.  However, the other methods use const arrays and I need to pull my values from the db.

Comment: I think `displayChoices.payment_code` is what is actually undefined, just below your logs

Comment: How/where is `displayChoices` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the property you show is part of the assignment to `displayChoices`, i.e. it's something like:

```
displayChoices = {
    ...
    payment_code: {
        label: "Payment Code",
        value: 'payment_code',
        choices: adminSalesStore.paymentCodes.map((payment_code) => {
            console.log(payment_code);
            console.log(payment_code['id']);
            console.log(payment_code['name']);
            displayChoices.payment_code[payment_code['id']] = payment_code['name'];
            return {
                label: payment_code['id'],
                value: payment_code['name']
            }
        }),
        type: 'choice'
    },
    ...
};
```

The problem is that until this statement finishes, there's no `displayChoices.payment_code` property, so you can't assign to `displayChoices.payment_code[anything]`.

You should do that assignment after you finish the first assignment.

```
displayChoices = {
    ...
    payment_code: {
        label: "Payment Code",
        value: 'payment_code',
        type: 'choice'
    },
    ...
};

displayChoices.choices = adminSalesStore.paymentCodes.map((payment_code) => {
    console.log(payment_code);
    console.log(payment_code['id']);
    console.log(payment_code['name']);
    displayChoices.payment_code[payment_code['id']] = payment_code['name'];
    return {
        label: payment_code['id'],
        value: payment_code['name']
    }
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's `displayChoices.payment_code` that is undefined. 
`displayChoices` is defined, or it would be complaining about setting the payment code for that, so I would define `displayChoices.payment_code = []` or `{}` (depending on what you're going for) before running this block of code. Or possibly you're looking for `displayChoices.paymentCodes`, which would be more like your previous choice of `adminSalesStore.paymentCodes`, and would make more sense to me. Not sure without seeing more of your code.